# Change java project source in VSCode?

Tags: java, spring, gradle, visual-studio-code

After creating the basic hello world Spring Java [application](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/) I am getting this lint error for the 'hello' package definition:

```
The declared package "hello" does not match the expected package "main.java.hello"
```

I understand in Eclipse you can change the Java source directory to be /src/main/java instead of just /src. How can I achieve the same in VSCode?

Answer (score 1):

You can right-click on src/main/java in Explorer and choose "Add Folder to Java Source Path", and restart VSCode.

Comment: Does anyone know what this actually does? It would make sense if I could save this in the repository or a settings file so other developers don't have to be instructed to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

In the .vscode/settings file set

```
"java.project.sourcePaths": [
     "src/main/java"
 ]
```

or edit the Workspace settings and find the java.sourcePaths property.